# MySQL find minimum not used value with additional condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `tbl` MySQL like this:

```
+----+------+
| id | col2 |
+----+------+
| 1  | AAA  |
| 1  | BBB  |
| 2  | AAA  |
| 3  | AAA  |
| 3  | BBB  |
| 4  | AAA  |
+----+------+
```

How to select first unused id for `col2` where `col2="BBB"` (example return 2).

The basic query is:

```
SELECT t1.id+1 AS UnusedID 
FROM tbl AS t1 
LEFT JOIN tbl AS t2 ON t1.id+1 = t2.id 
WHERE t2.id IS NULL 
ORDER BY t1.id LIMIT 1;
```

But how to add condition `cl2="BBB"`?

Comment: I can think of no sensible reason why you would wan to do this.

Comment: The table has several more columns.
id is a line order while col2 a category.
id is not primary key

Comment: My comment stands (albeit with a typographical error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a condition in the `ON` clause and the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT t1.id + 1 AS UnusedID 
FROM tbl t1 LEFT JOIN
     tbl t2
     ON t1.id + 1 = t2.id AND t2.col2 = t1.col2
WHERE t1.col2 = 'BBB' AND t2.id IS NULL 
ORDER BY t1.id
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: @DomenicoFormoso . . . The condition in the `where` clause needs to be on the first table not the second.